# How to replace 0 values in data frame columns by the value in the same column before, so (n-1)

Tags: r, replace

I ran this code to calculate log returns from a data frame "df" and created another data frame "df2":

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df[2:22], function(x) diff(log(x))))
```

My data frame "df2" has now 21 columns (INDEX, S1, S2, .... S20) and 4321 rows. I would like to replace zero values by values from the same column, but from the row above.
E.g. column 1 / row 100 has a "0" stored as value. I want to have the value from column 1 / row 99 to be copied to row 100.

How can I do it in a simple way? Since I am quite new to R, I try to improve my knowledge. Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What if row 99 has a "0" too?

Comment: what if the 0 occurs on the first row?

Comment: That is no problem, as long there is at least one value in the column that is not zero. The very first row has no zero values. So the rest can be filled up with the previous rows values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a value is 0 then replace this value with the lagged value (the preceding value) of the same column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidy)
library(purrr)

df$col <- ifelse(df$col == 0, lag(df$col), df$col)
```

For columns with consecutive zeros (as per your comment), replace 0 with NA, then fill down (i.e. replace all NAs with the preceding non-NA value:

e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(col = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0))
df$col <- na_if(df$col, 0)
df
   col
1    1
2    1
3   NA
4   NA
5   NA
6    3
7    3
8   NA
9    1
10  NA    

fill(df, col, .direction = "down")

   col
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    3
7    3
8    3
9    1
10   1
```

To do this for all your columns use  `dmap` from the `purrr` package to replace 0s with NAs across all columns. Then use `fill` to fill in the NAs with the value in the preceding columns. `col1:col3` refers to the range of columns that you want to apply `fill` to (i.e. columns 1-3) - change the column names to the ones in your dataframe.

```
df <- df %>% dmap(~na_if(., 0))

fill(df, col1:col3, .direction = "down")
```

Comment: How can I run this code for the whole data frame?
If I wrote:

    df2$INDEX <- ifelse(df2$INDEX == 0, lag(df2$INDEX), df2$INDEX)

I have certain intervals within the rows with consecutive zero values. i.e. row 100 to row 120 there are only zeros. This code, just filled row 100 with the values from row 99. How can I "run" this code automatically until there are no more zero values?

Comment: Note that this now requires the tidy package also.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I run this:

    df2$INDEX <- ifelse(df2$INDEX == 0, lag(df2$INDEX), df2$INDEX)
    df2$INDEX <- na_if(df2$INDEX, 0)
    fill(df2, INDEX, .direction = "down")

Now I have the NAs in the INDEX column, but it does not replace them after running "fill". And there is no error message :-/

Can I run a function to do all this for the whole data frame? Otherwise I have to write the code for each column.

Comment: okay, I have edited the post again to handle all of your columns. As for your issue I do not know why the function is now working for your data. If you provide a reproducible example of your data it will be easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I created this sample data:
value1 <- c(2, 0, 1, 0, 3)
value2 <- c(1, 0, 5, 6, 0)
value3 <- c(3, 0, 0, 7, 8)
value4 <- c(2, 0, 2, 0, 1)
index <- c(9, 0, 0, 0, 1)
df0 <- data.frame(value1, value2, value3, value4, index)

My question is also, what do I have to replace in your code, to be able to use it for my data frame. Let's use as an example this sample data. I.e. "df" has to replaced with "df2" in my case. Do I have to make changes to "dmap" or "names"? I am quite new, so still learning how to read R codes in a correct way.

Comment: I have edited the post again to make this clearer. You need to change the name of the dataframe and the name of the columns in your dataframe in the last piece of code in my post. The code I have provided works on the data in your example values.

Comment: Works perfectly, now I understand how this affects the code. Thank you very much!